# Is it possible to keep case when using inspect element in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, inspect-element

Google Chrome's inspect element seems to force all tags to be lower case.  Is there a way to disable that behavior so that the tag appears as it is written?

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, tags are non case specific, so even though `<p>Hello.</P>` wouldn't work in XML, it's fine in HTML.

Using an XHTML DOCTYPE might fix it though. I haven't tested it though.

Out of curiosity, why do you want this behavior?

Comment: I am parsing someone's code to do my own automatic form submission. In some cases it is easier to do an exact match. Probably more appropriate is to use case-insensitive regular expressions and string comparisons.  I was just curious if that was an option I was missing.